# Open only one submenu when clicked on the parent in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, menu, submenu

I'm trying to build a menu with a submenu. I used forEach to loop over the menu items and inside of it I used a for loop to show the submenu for that specific menu. However when I click on the parent menu all the submenus appear (Example 1 below)

I'm fairly new to Javascript. Is there a way to fix this? or maybe a better way to do it?.

Thanks!

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK9S1.png)

Here is the JS code:

```
const menuLink = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link-mobile");

const subMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile-submenu");

menuLink.forEach(function (element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < subMenu.length; i++) {
      subMenu[i].classList.toggle("mobile-submenu-visible");
      console.log(subMenu.length);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML, or an reproductible exemple it is difficult to says.

But try adding the index.

```
menuLink.forEach(function (element, index) {
  element[index].addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < subMenu.length; i++) {
      subMenu[i].classList.toggle("mobile-submenu-visible");
      console.log(subMenu.length);
    }
  });
```

If it is not that I will need more from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `click` Event on the `menuLink`, that when clicked *(called)* loops over every `subMenu` item. You want to put the `click` Event directly on the `subMenu`. I would do something like:

```
let sub;
for(let m of menuLink){ 
  sub = m.querySelectorAll('.mobile-submenu');
  for(let s of sub){
    s.onclick = function(){ 
      this.classList.toggle('mobile-submenu-visible');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: m.querySelectorAll is not a function"

Comment: That should work. Given than `const menuLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link-mobile');` is a nodeList, `m` would be each child node of that node. We then assign a nodeList to `sub`. As long as `m` is a node, that would be a function.